# Вызов ошибки 403

Tags: django

День добрый! Как правильно осуществить вызов ошибки Forbidden(403)?

```
urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url, handler403
handler403 = 'mysite.views.forbidden_403'
```

Описали функцию:

```
def forbidden_403(request):
   return render(request, "403.html", {})
```

И на этом все. Как ее вызвать в случае 403 и как вообще 403 сообщить клиенту и отдать старицу?

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

def forbidden_403(request):
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```